# Can I make my computer a server for internet service

Tags: networking

I have a computer which is connected to Internet using PPP(modem)..

Can I make my computer a server for some specific domain.

Comment: You probably can do it, but you won't be able to serve very much through a dial-up connection!

Answer (score 1):

If your ISP doesn't block incoming requests to your computer or isn't providing you with a private address, then yes.

Comment: in ppp you basically have a private ip..........ie. a subnet structure

Comment: @peril - I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Publicly addresses can easily be used on PPP interfaces.  I am not sure where you got the idea that using PPP means you must have a private address.  The question is more about how your ISP has chosen to set things up.  An ISP can use private addresss, and PPP interfaces can even be left un-numbered.

Answer (score 0):

If your ISP gives you a public IP then you can do so easily, but you'll probably need some service like DynDNS or No-IP since you will probably not have a static IP and it will change every time you disconnect. The good thing about using these services is that you can forward them to a specific port on your computer since most ISPs block port 80.